# How to use different TabBar's when i click a tabbar item?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController in my mainWindow.xib,when i click on a tabbar item in UITabBarController i want a new view to appear with different UITabBarController....So pls help me to do this by suggesting me tutorials and examples ...

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add new tabBar in the new view which is opening with your tabbar item and hide the present tabbar

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setHidden:YES];
```

Then go on

Comment: I have already given you, just add [[UITabBar appearance] setHidden:YES]; after touching your tab bar item and change your name in your profile, that is not your name

Answer (score 4):

What you'r like to do is against the [HIG](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=apple%20hig&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html&ei=HcWLT4_XK8vDtAa47u3NCw&usg=AFQjCNE17Vky3OsDv6jcESIVf1Hu6qB8aw) and will confuse users using your app.
What about placing your sub-tabbar-navigation within a `UITableView` and then use a `UINavigationController` to navigate?
That would be the apple-like-way.

Comment: could u pls give me sample code to use the way u have suggested

Comment: @user1285402: what Jonas is saying is true: application with that kind of behaviour would definetly not pass the approval proccess. It's hard to give a code example since first you're gonna have to rethink your viewcontroller layout and hierarchy. Check [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1)

Comment: yes , you are right, i don't know that apple wont accept this, but can you give a good solution for @user1285402 have two tab bars in application, i am also thinking in which way will apple accept it